# How can I lock all DB updates for all users but one (admin)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, nhibernate

We have a process that needs to run every so soften against a DB used by a web app, and we need to prevent all other updates during this process execution. Is there any global way to do this maybe thru nHibernate, .NET or maybe directly in Oracle?

The original idea was to have a one-record DB table to indicate if the process is running or not, but with this we will need to go back to every single save/update method and make changes to verify if this record exist or not prior to the save/update call.

Comment: What about disabling all user accounts except the Admins?

Comment: Adding On Insert / On Update / On Delete triggers voiding those operations by checking this other table might be a (bad) DBA /DML way to solve it. Also depends on how many other applications use the DB if its feasible to do it in code instead of in-DB....

Answer (score 1):

My reaction to that kind of requirement is to review the design as it is highly unusual outside of doing application upgrades.  Other than that there are a couple option:

Shutdown the DB, open it in exclusive mode, make changes, and then open it up for everyone.

Attempt to lock all the required tables with LOCK TABLE.  That might generate deadlock exceptions depending on the order of doing the locks.

Comment: An alternative to shutting down the database is `alter system enable restricted session`. The catch is that we need to kick off any connected normal sessions to obtain actual exclusivity.